# Why Symfony says APC isn't installed when it is?

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I installed Symfony with composer and when I did environment check it told me to install APC and to turn off short open tags in php.ini. But after I've done all this steps and restarted apache2 I run tests again and imagine my confusion when symfony gave me the same warnings again.

I'm 100% sure I installed APC, since I can see it is enabled in `phpinfo` and I can see it's status on `apc.php` page. In order to disable short open tags I edited `php.ini` which I found in `/etc/php5/apache2/`. And again phpinfo says that short open tags are indeed disabled but why `check.php` still gives me warnings about it?

BTW Symfony also told me to instal intl extension and it noticed that I installed intl, but failed to notice APC and short open tags. What can be the reason? Should I ignore these warnings or what??

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in the [installation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php) and [runtime configuration](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php) guides. Are you running WAMP or LAMP? Do you use cPanel or Plesk?...

Comment: @War10ck I am doing it on my localhost and I am using LAMP, and yes I followed guides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apache2 and cli uses two different php interpreter, and each one has its own php.ini file. So, .. maybe there are two different configurations. What do you mean with "symfony told me". Are you in console mode or in your web browser?

Comment: I am in console mode. And you were right/ I edited php.ini located in cli folder and Symfony is now satisfied with my server's configuration.